# sscanf with double quotes

Tags: c, arduino, scanf, double-quotes, openweathermap

I'm using an Arduino and [Open Weather Map API](http://openweathermap.org/current) to create a weather station, but I'm having serious trouble to parse the response into something useful with sscanf.

Here is one response example:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":14.17,"pressure":1012,"humidity":74,"temp_min":13,"temp_max":15.8},"wind":{"speed":4.6,"deg":150},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1459602835,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0059,"country":"GB","sunrise":1459575095,"sunset":1459622222},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

I would like to parse the weather info (Clear) from:

```
"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear",
```

And the temp info (14) from:

```
"main":{"temp":14.17,
```

This is the code, I'm using:

```
if (character == '}') { // Just a delimiter
      if (strstr(response, "\"weather\":[{")) { // to confirm that the string was found
        sscanf(response, ",main\":%s,", weather);
        Serial.printfn("\r\nfound weather = %s"), weather;
      }
      else if (strstr(response, "\"main\":{\"temp\":")) { // to confirm that the string was found
        sscanf(response, "temp\":%2s,", temp);
        Serial.printfn("\r\nfound temp = %s"), temp;
      }
      memset(response, 0, sizeof(response));
      idx = 0;
    }
```

But the sscanf seens to not even beeing working, since it always print the whole weather / temp strings 32 bytes long.

```
found weather = ,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":
found temp = ],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":14.17,"pressure":1011,"humi
```

Anyone have any clue how to parse these string using sscanf?

Comment: Use `%[^\"]` to indicate "until i read `\"`"

Comment: Do you have `sscanf_s` available? Or does Boost.Spirit exist for Arduinos?

Comment: is 'Serial.printfn("\r\nfound weather = %s"), weather;' correct? should it not be 'Serial.printfn("\r\nfound weather = %s", weather);' ?

Comment: Here is a [Demo](https://ideone.com/4f5VAX). Use it together with what @user3121023  wrote.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 indeed. that was the problem... damm, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an [example](https://ideone.com/4f5VAX). Translate it to any C-Dialect you need.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

const char* haystack = "\"weather\":[{\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",";
const char* needle   = "\"main\":";

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Parsing string: '" << haystack << "'\n";

    if (const char* cursor = strstr(haystack, needle)) {
        char buffer[100];
        if (sscanf(cursor, "\"main\":\"%99[^\"]\",", buffer))
            std::cout << "Parsed string: '" << buffer << "'\n";
        else 
            std::cout << "Parsing error!\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Could not find '" << needle << "' in '" << haystack << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: + for the nice choice of variable names ;)

Answer (score 0):

if Serial.printfn is a pointer to a function which work like printf(), then

```
Serial.printfn("\r\nfound weather = %s"), weather;
```

is undefined Behavior, and may print what you see.
you should use

```
Serial.printfn("\r\nfound weather = %s", weather);
```